# How do I remove the hyphens in this string (more complex than it sounds!)

Tags: javascript, string

I must first confess that I understand very little JS and this is a bastardised version of some code I picked up elsewhere. Essentially it runs through a collection of list-items and extracts their class names (which are being populated by a CMS to reflect for example "Brand" or "Manufacturer") builds them into a string, splits the string into arrays and dedupes them. It then creates a list of unique check boxes based on the class name which, when selected or deselected, filters the list-items on the page using jquery.

My problem is, that because the string of class names is being split by a 'space' if the value of the class consists of multiple-words the values populating the class must be hyphenated.

BUT... when the label for the checkbox is generated on the page by the script I wonder if it is possible to remove the hyphen without upsetting the logic generating it.

Here is the code I have so far, if you drop this into an HTML file you will see how it works (the jquery file is hosted elsewhere).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.chewbz.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/**
 * Removes duplicates in the array 'a'
 */
function unique(a) {
    tmp = new Array(0);
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(!contains(tmp, a[i])){
            tmp.length+=1;
            tmp[tmp.length-1]=a[i];
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

/**
 * Returns true if 's' is contained in the array 'a'
 */

function contains(a, e) {
    for(j=0;j<a.length;j++)if(a[j]==e)return true;
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // create a string of class names, 
    var stringOfClassNames = '';

    // grab the class name of each list item to build that string
    $('.filterThis > li').each( function (i) {
        var thisClassString = $(this).attr('class');
        stringOfClassNames = stringOfClassNames +' '+ thisClassString
    });

    // Trim spaces from the ends of that string:
    stringOfClassNames = jQuery.trim(stringOfClassNames);

    // convert the string to an array.
    var arrayClasses = stringOfClassNames.split(' ');

    // pull out only unique values from that array
    arrayUniqueClasses = (unique(arrayClasses));

    // we only want to create filters if there are multiple classes
    if (arrayUniqueClasses.length > 1) {

        // create box for filters
        $('<div class="filters" id="filters"><\/div>').insertBefore('.filterThis');

        // create the filter checkboxes based on all the class names
        $.each(arrayUniqueClasses, function() {
            $('<div class="filter-options"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'+this+'" class="filter-checkbox" id="filterID'+this+'" />'+this+'<\/div>').appendTo('.filters');
        });

        // create a 'show all' checkbox
        $('<div class="filter-options-all"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="filterAll" class="filter-checkbox" id="filterIDall" />Show All<\/div>').appendTo('.filters');

        // create a close button
        $('<img src="" id="filter-close" onClick="document.getElementById(\'filters\').style.display = \'none\'"><\/div>').appendTo('.filters');

        // the filter part
        $('.filters input').click( function() {
            var value= $(this).val();
            if (value == 'filterAll') {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('.filters input').attr('checked','checked');
                    $('.filterThis li').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    var one=1;
                }
            } else {
                stringValue = '.filterThis > li.'+value;
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(stringValue).fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $(stringValue).fadeOut();
                    $('.filters #filterIDall').removeAttr('checked');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>

<style>
<!-- 
ul.filterThis {
list-style-type:none;
}
ul.filterThis li {
width:200px;height:200px;background:#eee;border:solid 1px #ccc;float:left;margin:10px;
}
-->
</style>

<ul class="filterThis">

    <li class="Medium-Jars">
        <div class="product-container">
        Medium Jars
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Large-Jars">
        <div class="product-container">
        Large Jars
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Sweets">
        <div class="product-container">
        Sweets
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Medium-Jars">
        <div class="product-container">
        Medium Jars
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="Sweets">
        <div class="product-container">
        Sweets
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ever heard of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
// create the filter checkboxes based on all the class names
$.each(arrayUniqueClasses, function() {
   $('<div class="filter-options"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'+this+'" class="filter-checkbox" id="filterID'+this+'" />'+this+'<\/div>').appendTo('.filters');
});
```

To

```
// create the filter checkboxes based on all the class names
$.each(arrayUniqueClasses, function() {
   $('<div class="filter-options"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'+this+'" class="filter-checkbox" id="filterID'+this+'" />'+this.replace('-',' ')+'<\/div>').appendTo('.filters');
});
```

A simple `.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

> because the string of class names is being split by a 'space' if the value of the class consists of multiple-words the values populating the class must be hyphenated.

Could the values populating the class use underscores in place of spaces, instead of hyphens? (I haven’t read the code, so apologies if my suggestion makes no sense.)

Comment: Class names can include hyphens, they make a lousey delimeter, if that is what is happening here.

Comment: Yep, together this was a great response, edited the code and delimited using underscores which were then translated to spaces meaning spaces and hyphens could be used. Thanks all!

Comment: @Dom: excellent! Glad to hear we helped. Thanks in the form of upvotes and answer acceptances are also gratefully received.